# subsetting a dataframe by existing object

Tags: r, subset

I have a predefined object `grade <- "G3"`. I would like to subset a data frame by grabbing 3 from "grade" object, subsetting only grade 3.

Here is an example of data

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
grade <- c(3,3,4,4,5)
score <- c(10,5,10,5,10)


data <- data.frame("id"=id,"grade"=grade, "score"=score)

> data
  id grade score
1  1     3    10
2  2     3     5
3  3     4    10
4  4     4     5
5  5     5    10
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
  > data
      id grade score
    1  1     3    10
    2  2     3     5
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to grab "3" from grade object (G3), then subset the data based on this grade object information. I think you are trying to paste "G" to data$grade.

Answer (score 2):

With `tidyverse`, we can use `!!` to check for the 'grade' object in the global environment instead of the column in the 'data' environment, remove the 'G' and do a `==`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data %>%
    filter(grade == str_remove(!!grade, "G"))
#  id grade score
#1  1     3    10
#2  2     3     5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter`, but you would likely want to change the object name so it doesn't match the variable name.

```
Grade <- "G3"

data <- data.frame("id"=id,"grade"=grade, "score"=score) %>%
  filter(paste0("G", grade) == Grade)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use readr's `parse_number` to extract digits from a string with a minimum of fuss, and then subset with the result:

```r
library(readr)

data[data$grade == parse_number(grade),]
```

Or with base R's `sub` replace non-numbers with `""`:

```r
data[data$grade == sub("[^0-9]", "", grade),]
```

Or if the only other character in your string is always `"G"` then:

```r
data[data$grade == sub("G", "", grade),]
```